# SVG Cursor URL color is different to background-image color even though the hex codes are the same

Tags: html, svg, cursor, background-color, fill

A bit of a strange one, as we have used the same HEX code for a background colour and a SVG colour for the cursor..

However, even though the HEXs match, the colours look different?

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Here is a code pen -> https://codepen.io/l0u13e/pen/PomjRKG

Thanks

HTML

```
<div class="button">
  
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3C%3Fxml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'%3F%3E%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' height='34' width='34' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 32 32' style='enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Cstyle type='text/css'%3E .st0%7Bfill:%23008E85;%7D%0A%3C/style%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpath class='st0' d='M27.3,27.3C24.1,30.4,20.4,32,16,32s-8.1-1.6-11.3-4.7C1.6,24.1,0,20.4,0,16S1.6,7.9,4.7,4.7 C7.9,1.6,11.6,0,16,0s8.1,1.6,11.3,4.7C30.4,7.9,32,11.6,32,16S30.4,24.1,27.3,27.3'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A") 16 16, auto;

}

.button {
  background-color: #008e85;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: To my eye the colours look the same but the cursor border makes it look peculiar

Answer (score 0):

I am certain those are the same colours.
Do you have to use SVG as it is an image representation?

Here is a website that maps that colour to every format (Scroll down for SVG images).

https://convertingcolors.com/rgb-color-0_140_133.html?search=RGB(0,%20140,%20133)